# Need Date Format explanation

Tags: date, datetime, time

Can anyone please explain me the date format?

2015-10-14T10:07:13.024Z

Does 10:07:13.024Z mean today morning 10:07 am?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Z is actually part of the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) datetime and is used in the UTC dates.

To be specific Z means "Zulu time"

> Does 10:07:13.024Z mean today morning 10:07 am?

The answer is Yes.

Comment: @trx:- I didnt get that. As I said when you write the Z format date then it is representing the UTC time.